# Cannot read property '0' of undefined (only on unit test)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I don't understand why I'm getting the following error :

> Chrome 43.0.2357 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Requests controller test should
>   fill properties from result from xhr requests FAILED
>           TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>               at getLastStatus (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/app/tools.js:68:43)
>               at C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/app/requests/requests.js:238:42
>               at processQueue (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14792:28)
>               at C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14808:27
>               at Scope.$eval (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16052:28)
>               at Scope.$digest (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15870:31)
>               at Scope.$apply (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16160:24)
>               at done (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10589:47)
>               at handleResponse (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1194:9)
>               at Function.$httpBackend.flush (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/Front/Balrog-UI/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1553:26)

This error is showed only on the karma logs.

But it shouldn't be undefined because of a loop condition.

In the tools.js file :

```
function getLastStatus(statuses) {
  var lastStatusDate = Date.parse(statuses[0].date); // this is the line pointed in the error
  var lastIndex = 0;

  for (var i = 0; statuses[i]; i++) {
    var currentStatusDate = Date.parse(statuses[i].date);

    if (currentStatusDate > lastStatusDate) {
      lastStatusDate = currentStatusDate;
      lastIndex = i;
    }
  }
  return statuses[lastIndex];
}
```

In the requests.js file :

```
Requests.query().$promise.then(function(result) {
      controllerScope.requestsList = [];
      for (var i = 0; result[i]; i++) {
        var currentRequest = {
          id: result[i]["id"],
          projectTitle: result[i]["project"].title,
          status: getLastStatus(result[i]["statuses"]).status, // this is the line pointed in the error
          description: result[i]["description"],
          regions: regionsIdToName(controllerScope.regionsList, result[i]["project"].regions),
          requestDate: moment(result[i]["request_date"]).format("MM-DD-YYYY"),
          developers: result[i]["developers"],
          statusDate: moment(getLastStatus(result[i]["statuses"]).date).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
        };
        controllerScope.requestsList.push(currentRequest);
      }
    });
```

**EDIT :** When adding `console.log(statuses);` at the first ine of the `getLastStatus(statuses)` function :

An array of object is displayed on the browser console, like it should.

But undefined is displayed on the Karma console. So I don't get what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue came from the test file. The expected response passed to the `respond` method of `$httpBackend` was missing some attributes.

Answer (score 1):

`result[i]` can't be undefined (due to the loop check). But it seems `result[i]["statuses"]` is undefined. You pass undefined to getLastStatus and then try to get it's '0' element. You should check whether `result[i]["statuses"]` is undefined.

Comment: Every `result[i]` has a statuses field. Besides, the error would be `cannot read property statuses` if that was the issue.

Comment: @Ellone No If you request a not existing property you get null.

Comment: I would try to console.log 'statuses' at the beginning of getLastStatus. Maybe it will help.

Comment: @ceving I don't get your point, I was just stating that seeing the error, the problem didn't come from the statuses field.

Comment: @PavelRudko An array of object is displayed in the console in the browser , like it should. But undefined is displayed on the karma console. So I'm wondering if this is not caused by Karma